# How to display HTML in an EE field, onto an EE template?

Tags: ee2

I'm running an older version of EE (v2.6.1) and I need to create a template to export some of the content. I need to display entry fields as their HTML, so that when I view this template, I can see the HTML tags and then copy that HTML into my shiny new instance of EE.

(Please don't suggest importing; I don't have the SQL knowledge to do that. this method is slower, but I know what the frick I'm doing and I know that it won't kill anything. The entries have been created in the new version of EE, so the entry IDs won't align between the two instances anyway. Manual copying is going to have to be what happens.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to use a migration utility - such utilities allow you to export channel entries in various formats and then reimport them somewhere else (either a different CMS, or another instance of EE etc.).

A good one is [Datagrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab)

Comment: Except I've already manually created the entry stubs, so the entry IDs won't sync up. And I have added new content, so I don't want to wipe and start over.

Comment: What are the stubs u mentioned? And why are their IDs so implicit? Export/import module would take about 10mins go to wo.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to the EE support folks, found that there is no real way to do this in EE because the browser will still render the HTML. Instead, what I did is a global search-and-replace to change all instances of the left bracket to &lt;. This meant that all of the HTML in the fields that I did a search-and-replace, displayed as HTML code in the EE templates. Note for folks reading this: yes, this is reversible, BUT be careful when doing it, that you really want to do this.